NGPM doesn't load the css of wordpress
I am running a server with docker installed.
I have 1 container running NGINX Proxy Manager and 1 container running wordpress that is accesible trough NGPM with a domain.
But when i go to the page i only see the plain text with no css or something.
Does anyone know how to fix this??

